# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Data conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to import data from a flat file, my table has 3 columns,

1. id - int - auto_increment - primary key
2. profileID - int
3. taken - bit

This is what my flat file looks like:

```
profileID
79518
27835
26853
15052
11165
67092
57399
```

There is 10,000 rows

and I keep getting this error when I try in import

```
Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "profileID" returned status value 6 and status text "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
```

I set the Data Type as single-byte signed integer [DT_I1] for profileID for the flat file.

Please Help!

Comment: Obviously a single byte is not big enough. Either change it to double or convert as character coming in and then change it in the table after the import.

Comment: Try `DT_I4` as the data type.